# Set up authorization for user roles nested in groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, authorization

I am working on a project where I am using role authorization for the first time and I can't get it to work.

The thing is that the project is set up in a way that when a new user is created, they are added to a group. These groups contain one ore more roles.
For example the group "ReadOnly" contains the roles "userReadOnly" and "groupsReadOnly" (this user can go in to the pages user and groups, see the data, but not edit it)

The part that I do get is the `[Authorize(Roles = "..., ...")]` in the controllers and `@if(user.IsInRole("...")` in the views, but when I add this to the project things stop working. I know I need to create a custom `AccountRoleProvider`, but here I get stuck. I don't understand how to do this and I don't understand how to adapt the (standard)providers that are found online to fit my project. A nudge in the right direction, or an explanation of what the provider actually does would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom authorization filter you need to create a folder in your solution and add a file named AuthorizedRoles.cs inside it.

AuthorizedRoles.cs file as:

```
 sealed class AuthorizedRoles : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
       public string Roles { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var status = false;
            string[] roles = Roles.Split(',');
            var currentUserRole = Session.UserRole; // Get here the role of the user
            var Role = "";
            switch (currentUserRole)
            {
                case 1:
                    Role = "Role1";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Role = "Role2";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Role = "Role3";
                    break; // Check here for more role
                default:
                    break;
            }

          if (Role != ""){
                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    if (role.Contains(currentRoleName))
                    {
                        status = true;
                    }
                }
            }

      if (status == false)//That means user is not in the role, so redirect it to the new controller returning a view showing information that you are not autorized
            {
              if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    //The request can be ajax callso it will redirect to another ajax method
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "ControllerName",
                        action = "AjaxActionName",
                        area = ""
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                    {
                        controller = "ControllerName",
                        action = "ActionName",
                        area = ""
                    }));
}
         }
      base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

}
```

The redirection methods will be like;

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
        {
            return View(); //Create view for this action
        }

public JsonResult AjaxActionName()
        {
            return Json(new { status = false, message = "Unauthorized access." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Above any method where you want a check can be used to call custom authorization filter :

```
//This method will execute only if the user have Role1 and Role2 other wise redirected to other no permission methods before the action executes.
  [AuthorizedRoles(Roles = "Role1,Role2")]
        public ActionResult NeedPermissionAction(int id)
        {

}
```